# Make part of albedo transparent

Tags: shaders, godot

I have a shader which creates a circle inside of a plane mesh. I would like to get get rid of the parts around the circle, which are the `r` and `b` parts of the `ALBEDO` but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

The only thing I've managed to find is `ALPHA` but that changes the transparency of the entire shader and not just parts of it.

```
shader_type spatial;

float circle(vec2 position, float radius, float feather)
{
    return smoothstep(radius, radius + feather, length(position - vec2(0.5)));
}

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = vec3(0, circle(UV - vec2(0), 0.5, 0.005), 0);
}
```

Which currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALPHA` is what you want, except you want to set it to `1` anywhere you want it be transparent. So, we can reuse your `circle` function and do this:

```
shader_type spatial;

float circle(vec2 position, float radius, float feather)
{
    return smoothstep(radius, radius + feather, length(position - vec2(0.5)));
}

void fragment() {
    ALBEDO = vec3(0, circle(UV - vec2(0), 0.5, 0.005), 0);
    ALPHA = 1.0 - circle(UV - vec2(0), 0.5, 0.005);
}
```

*Yes, you could put `circle(UV - vec2(0), 0.5, 0.005)` in a variable and use that instead of calling `circle` twice, I didn't bother.*

Note that if I didn't put `1.0 - /*...*/`  I would have the circle transparent, but we want the parts around the circle transparent instead.

This is how it looks like:

[image: The shader code above in Godot]